# eclipse/subclipse project not showing red line errors

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax-error

I'm working on a group project for school. I checked the project out from the repository. When I write code, the red lines for syntax errors don't show up. So I made a separate java project on my machine and red line errors do show up there. So I don't know whats going on.

Comment: Are you sure your original project is a Java project? In other words, is the .project file setup correctly? If the .project file doesn't specify that it is a Java project, then Eclipse isn't going to do any of the fancy stuff that it normally does with a Java project.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse suddenly stopped showing compile errors, both in the code and in the Problems view.

I had created a Dynamic Web Project, added a servlet and everything was groovy; compilation errors showed up properly.

I did right click on MyProject->Configure->ConvertToMavenProject and problems started. In my  BuildPath, the JRE version was changed from 1.6 to 1.5; this caused some previously unreported compilation problems that went away as soon as I change back to 1.6.

But now, no compilation errors showed up in the code.

The reason was, converting to a maven project also removed my src folder from the build path. I added the src folder back to the build path and things are peachy.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click your project and go to *Properties > Java Build Path > Source*.

Make sure your source directory (for example *MyProject/src*) is listed as a Source folder. Otherwise you won't get any red markers.

Answer (score 1):

Squiggles are configurable; in Preferences see General -> Appearance -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations and the "Errors" annotation type.

Comment: I guess his question was not how to hide those red lines but how to resolve them!

Comment: @ram I don't believe so; OP is asking why they don't show up in one environment and do in another.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your .project file looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>ProjectName</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

If it doesn't look like the above, then you aren't going to get syntax checking, as well as a number of other features that come along with Java projects.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well.   After a project --> clean, I'm back to normal.

Edit ... Happened again - realized that I had accidentally unchecked the "Project --> build-automatically" menu option.   Now working as expected.

Comment: Thank you so so much to share this with us. I'm struggling with this problem from last 3-4 days. But didn't get rid of the issue. After reading your solution, it resolves. +1

Answer (score 0):

Go to check whether in your Java Build Path -> Libraries  has a missing jar.
When I remove that missing jar in my case, the auto-error shows again.